# Turn on swap memory on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, swap

For some reason on my Ubuntu 9.04 desktop, swap memory is turned off. How can I turn it back on?

Comment: Did you installed with Ext4 as filesystem? I read it somewhere that with ext4 and enough ram it's not necessary to have a swap partition anymore. Can't find the link now though.

Comment: How would a file system be able to avoid swapping?

Comment: How do you know that "swap memory is turned off"?

Comment: the filesystem used and the need of swap is hardly much related

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Check that you have a swap partition defined in */etc/fstab*.

  > $ grep swap /etc/fstab 
  >   UUID=14a0f7b9-dabb-4296-b0e7-013527a7d82d
  >   none swap sw 0 0
- Check that it is being used by the system

  > $ swapon -s 
  >   Filename              Type        Size    Used    Priority 
  >   /dev/sda6                             partition   1004020 215532  -1
- If it isn't, check that it is formatted as a swap partition.

  > $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda 
  >   [..snipped..] 
  >   /dev/sda5            3842        6595 
  >   22121473+  83  Linux 
  >   /dev/sda6        6596        6720     1004031   82 
  >   Linux swap / Solaris
- If it is a swap partition, ready it for use and turn it on. At this point, you might see any errors that prevented its use.

  > sudo mkswap /dev/sda6 
  >   sudo swapon /dev/sda6
- Check that the partition is now being used using the *swapon -s* command from #2.
- Add an entry to */etc/fstab* to have this swap partition loaded at bootup. You can replace the *"UUID=xxx"* part from above with "*/dev/sda6*" so the entry looks like this.

  > /dev/sda6       none    swap    sw      0       0

If you didn't define a swap partition earlier, then you'd have to create one, or [point swap to a regular file](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/setting_up_swap.html) (less efficient).

Answer (score 5):

If you have a swap partition defined in /etc/fstab already then sudo swapon -a

If you don't have the swap partition listed in /etc/fstab then sudo swapon *device*

Answer (score 1):

A really easy way to do it is with these [scripts](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/scripting-linux-swap-space/), or even easier still with:

```
sudo apt install swapspace -y
```

Which is a [dynamic swapping daemon](http://pqxx.org/development/swapspace/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Disks (`gnome-disk-utility`) application. Select the partition formatted as swap and push the <kbd>▶</kbd> button.

[image]